# Writing a static method for the following code

Tags: java, arrays

I need to write up a static method that takes an array of Vehicles and print each registration number in the array. The object in the array is either a Vehicle, a Car, or a Truck object reference.  Finally, I need to print the registration number of the object on a single line on its own.

So the code is:

```
public class Vehicle {
   private String registrationNumber;        
   public Vehicle(String rego) {
       registrationNumber = rego;
    }        
    public String getRegistrationNumber() {
        return registrationNumber;
    }
}

public class Car extends Vehicle {
    int passengers;        
    public Car(String rego, int pass) {
        super(rego);
        passengers = pass;
    }        
    public int getPassengers() {
        return passengers;
    }
}

public class Truck extends Vehicle {
    int tons;     
    public Truck(String rego, int tons) {
        super(rego);
        this.tons = tons;
    }       
    public int getTons() {
        return tons;
    }
}
```

I have to write up a static method for the following test and get the following, but I am having some trouble.

[Test and expected Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7VPhk.jpg)

This is what I have done so far:

```
public static void printRegNum(Vehicle[] list){
    for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
        System.out.println(list[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The 1st way** to play with your `System.out.println(list[i]);` is to override the `toString()` method in class `Vehicle`:

```
public class Vehicle {
    private String registrationNumber;        
    public Vehicle(String rego) {
       registrationNumber = rego;
    }        
    public String getRegistrationNumber() {
       return registrationNumber;
    }
    public String toString() {
       return registrationNumber;
    }
}
```

**The 2nd way** is change:

from:

```
System.out.println(list[i]);
```

to:

```
System.out.println(list[i].getRegistrationNumber());
```

Hope those can help.

Answer (score 0):

Not getting where's the problem

i.e.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
  Car car = new Car("MYCAR",4);
  Truck t = new Truck("MYTRUCK", 16);
  Vehicle[] myList = new Vehicle[] {car, t};
  printRegNum(myList);
}
```

Also seems that you only need to print the "rego".

```
System.out.println(list[i].getRegistrationNumber());
```